# Get record from array of objects after rendering to view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs.net

I've a component which passes javascript objects as props to another component for rendering. After rendering the records as divs, I want to get the clicked object record back for displaying it in a third component.

Each object contains multiple name-value pairs, but I'm only using limited fields for displaying initially. I'm stuck with getting back the entire object with all values. I'm new to React so any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
export class ViewList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.configs) {
            let summaryDisplay = this.props.configs.map((config) =>
                <ConfigSummary
                    key={config.id}
                    config={config}
                    onViewConfigClick={this.props.onViewConfigClick}
                />);
        } else
            return (null);
    }
}

class ConfigSummary extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className={cSummarySm}> {this.props.config.direction} </div>
                <div className={cSummaryMd}> {this.props.config.Object} </div>
                <div className={cSummarySm}> {this.props.config.version} </div >
                <div className={cSummaryLg}> {this.props.config.jobShortDescription} </div >
                <div className={cSummarySm}> <button className="btn btn-link" onClick={this.props.onViewConfigClick}>View</button></div >
            </div>);
    }
}
```

On clicking the view button, I'm calling the grandparent component which then calls the parent component to display the selected record in expanded view.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass some parameters in the `onClick` function.

You could do it like this:

```
onClick={()=>this.props.onViewConfigClick(this.props)}
```

This will pass all params into the grandparent function.

You cald also pass the id:

```
onClick={()=>this.props.onViewConfigClick(this.props.id)}
```

My tip: Pass the id as an object so you can later extend the function params easier if needed:

```
onClick={()=>this.props.onViewConfigClick({
    id: this.props.id
})}
```